# Disable Alfresco rest api basic auth popup

Tags: angular6, alfresco, basic-authentication, alfresco-webscripts

I am using Angular Version 6 & Alfresco community version 5.2

> "@alfresco/adf-content-services": "2.6.1",
>
> "@alfresco/adf-core": "2.6.1",

Is there any way to disable alfresco rest api basic auth popup?

[image]

I am calling alfresco webscripts from angular.

If I am not authenticated then this popup arrives & asks for user name & password after submitting it's arrives again & again.

Comment: Hi, I am guessing it will not be possible to restrict somehow, because Alfresco is using it itself as far as I know, in theory if its not needed by any "external" system, probably the most easy way can be restrict access to the given URL patter on the machine only for local connection (not sure how and depends on the OS- eg. iptables rules, or if you have some kind of reverse proxy in front of machine etc)

Comment: There was a talk at DevCon a couple of weeks back, but sadly slides and videos aren't posted yet :( IIRC there are 2 true/false values in the latest version that lets you control the login / sso etc. Look for `Francesco Corti - 
Alfresco Identity Services in Action: Welcome Common Authentication across the Alfresco Stack`

Comment: Thank you, @xxxvodnikxxx & Gagravarr for your quick response, 
Let me find & view your suggestions.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Were you able to disable the basic authentication in the alfresco rest api?

Comment: In the newer version of alfresco 6 it's solved and if you can modify the alfresco response header=> proxyRes.headers['www-authenticate'] = 'x' + header;
Then issue will get solved www-authenticate.